# Confusion regarding the use of @ in view classes of the Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

I am mostly guessing how to use `@` in Play. The following code compiles if I do not have a blank space between `if` and `(` but not otherwise. Also, I had to use `@` for `if` but not for `else` or the closing braces.

Questions:

1. Shouldn't I use @ for all code written in Scala?
2. What are the rules for using @ in a Play framework view?

This doesn't compile:

```
@if (userForm.value.isDefined) {
```

This does:

```
@if(userForm.value.isDefined) {
          <h1>@userForm.get.name (userForm.get.age)</h1>
          <h2>Lives at @userForm.get.address.fullStreet</h2>
        **} else { //no @ required!**
            <h1>Feed User Data</h1>
            @helper.form(action=routes.Data.post){
            @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit"/>
            } **//no @ required for closing braces!**
        }
```

Comment: In twirl templates `@xxxx` begins a "scala-code-block" so you do not need to use `@` again inside it.

Comment: You can refer to this [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates)

Comment: the templates are kinda awful, and don't work in some cases as you will see with experience. but have a look at the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates

Answer (score 1):

The special character `@` in the template language is often referred to as [*the magic character*](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Syntax:-the-magic-%E2%80%98@%E2%80%99-character) or [*twirl*](https://github.com/playframework/twirl#credits) (like the Play template engine). As the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Syntax:-the-magic-%E2%80%98@%E2%80%99-character) states, it indicates the beginning of a dynamic statement.

> Shouldn't I use @ for all code written in Scala?

No, just for the **beginning** of a **dynamic statement**. As you have already noticed, you don't need the magic character `@` for an `else` block, as it is part of the `if` statement.

> What are the rules for using @ in a Play framework view?

The only rule I can think of is that it is not necessary to explicitly close dynamic statements. Also, keep in mind to escape `@` with `@@`, e.g. `john@@doe.com`.

Read more about [Play's template engine](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#the-template-engine) and [common use cases](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#scala-templates-common-use-cases).